# How to make i18n in single js and twig js app

Tags: javascript, html, internationalization, twig, gettext

How to make i18n in single js and twig js app? Can't find solution to translate twig.. In angular used angular-gettext but it's not ng app.. 
Need similar solution for not ng app.. Maybe there is any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved by including angular gettext

gulpfile:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const gettext = require('gulp-angular-gettext');

gulp.task('extract', function () {
    return gulp.src(['src/**/*.html', 'src/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(gettext.extract('template.pot'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('translations/'));
});

gulp.task('translations', function () {
    return gulp.src(['translations/*.po'])
        .pipe(gettext.compile({
            format: 'json'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/i18n'));
});
```

js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const phrases = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('src/i18n/zh.json', 'utf8'));
const gettext = (text) => phrases.zh[text] || text;

Twig.extendFilter('translate', gettext);
```

decorating

js -

```
page().find('.dashboard-mentions').html(gettext("You haven't been mentioned yet."));
```

html -

```
<h4 class="text-label">{{ 'Title *' | translate }}</h4>
```